# Allow SSH access after port knocking from any source IP

Tags: ssh, iptables, firewall

I have a working port knocking setup for SSH on Linux using only iptables rules and the “recent” module following this tutorial: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Port_knocking#Port_knocking_with_iptables_only .

Now my problem is that several networks like my work network block traffic to non-standard ports like 22, 80, 443, so I can‘t send my knock packets. On the other hand, my mobile internet allows them.

As a workaround I would like to open the SSH port whenever the correct knocking sequence is sent from *any* host, not just the same host.

is there some way to achieve that with iptables? E.g. I could imagine a “state switch” or global variable that can be switched on by one rule and checked by another rule. It would fall back to “off” after a timeout.

Comment: You should give a try to FWknop. It is more secure than standard port knocking and you can configure such things inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to go knockd route. It's simpler this way. Only instead of using this default config

```
[openSSH]
        sequence    = 7000,8000,9000
        seq_timeout = 10
        tcpflags    = syn
        command     = /usr/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -s %IP% -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

  [closeSSH]
        sequence    = 9000,8000,7000
        seq_timeout = 10
        tcpflags    = syn
        command     = /usr/sbin/iptables -D INPUT -s %IP% -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

You would use this one (Note -s %IP% removed)

```
[openSSH]
        sequence    = 7000,8000,9000
        seq_timeout = 10
        tcpflags    = syn
        command     = /usr/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

  [closeSSH]
        sequence    = 9000,8000,7000
        seq_timeout = 10
        tcpflags    = syn
        command     = /usr/sbin/iptables -D INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```