# How to run a process if a machine is not listening on a port?

Tags: ssh, iptables, port-forwarding

I've got a machine with an IP bound to an interface that is used solely for port forwarding.

I would like these forwards to be up as much as possible.

Is it possible for iptables to catch requests on inactive ports to attempt to activate those ports (I have pre-defined destinations and ssh config scripts keyed off the bind address and port, so I'd know what to look for just off the denied port)?

If so, what does the iptables entry look like can you call an adhoc command from iptables (Is [this] the best way, can I pass the rejected IP and Port to the command?)?

Comment: Possibly related: [Allow SSH access after port knocking from any source IP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/319890/allow-ssh-access-after-port-knocking-from-any-source-ip)

Comment: @mark, I'll take a look at knockd, I don't know what it's features are - I already have the port open, I just don't have the listener running.

Comment: I'm confused—why don't you just have the iptables forward rules installed always?

Comment: @derobert, I'm not forwarding with iptables, I'm connecting to a server that manages ssh port forwards.  In the best case, those ssh processes are running and the port is open, but if it is not open, I'd like to check and see if it should be.

Comment: @PeterTurner Seems like you want systemd socket activation or inetd. To just spawn your ssh connections on-demand. Although I'm not 100% sure you can make that work with ssh forwards...